# How to code a C# Extension method to turn a Domain Model object into an Interface object?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, domain-driven-design, selectlist, selectlistitem

When you have a domain object that needs to display as an interface control, like a drop down list, [ifwdev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45852/ifwdev) suggested creating an extension method to add a .ToSelectList().

The originating object is a List of objects that have properties identical to the .Text and .Value properties of the drop down list.  Basically, it's a List of SelectList objects, just not of the same class name.

I imagine you could use reflection to turn the domain object into an interface object.  Anyone have any suggestions for C# code that could do this?  The SelectList is an MVC drop down list of SelectListItem.

The idea of course is to do something like this in the view:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("City", 
         (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewData["Cities"].ToSelectList() )
```

Comment: By reflection, I mean read the properties of the source object and match them to the SelectList properties, returning a proper DropDownList selection list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easier to make the `SelectList` part of your `ViewModel` object.

Anyway, you just have to loop through the `IEnumerable` and add each item to a new `SelectList` object and return it.

```
public static List<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Func<T, string> text, Func<T, string> value, string defaultOption) 
{ 
    var items = enumerable.Select(f => new SelectListItem() { Text = text(f), Value = value(f) }).ToList(); 
    items.Insert(0, new SelectListItem() { Text = defaultOption, Value = "-1" }); 
    return items; 
}
```

[How to refactor these 2 similar methods into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828624/how-to-refactor-these-2-similar-methods-into-one)

Comment: +1 for having the formated select list data in the view model. It's much easier and much easier to test.

Comment: If you please, do you have a link for the ViewModel pattern?  Are we talking about making a class for each view in addition to the domain models?  I supposed the repository won't return any of these, so do you use factories to create the view models?

Comment: Here you go: http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part6.htm. The ViewModel is a class object that contains all of the data you need to render the view (including things like SelectLists).

Comment: Heh.  I even have that book on my shelf and the notes in my notebook.  The part I was missing is: the interface elements are available in the controller.  Thanks ;)

Answer (score 4):

These are the two extension methods I use to create select lists.

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T, string> text, Func<T, string> value)
{
    return collection.ToSelectList(text, value, x => false);
}

public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T, string> text, Func<T, string> value, Func<T, bool> selected)
{
    return (from item in collection
            select new SelectListItem()
                       {
                           Text = text(item),
                           Value = value(item),
                           Selected = selected(item)
                       });
}
```

HTHs,
Charles